# How to create a dynamic ListView in phoneGap

Tags: list, cordova

I'm trying for a long time to create dynamic underscored list in Html. I'm Creating a Phone Gap application in which I'm Requesting to the server and get some data. According to this data I have to show this data in a list and data is dynamic so I have to create a dynamic list. please help me thank in advance

Comment: What type of data are you getting and what framework/libs used?

Answer (score 1):

to create a dynamic list in html is not a big deal.i m just giving you code for it.

```
function addOptioncity() { 

    var strs = cityarray;  //this is a array
    var list = document.getElementById('cityidm');

               for (var i in strs) {

                var anchor = anchor+i;
                    anchor = document.createElement("a");
                    anchor.href = "#";
                    anchor.innerText = "neeraj";
                    anchor.value = "10";
                $(anchor).on("click",function(){
                   //currentcityval=this.value;
                   //currentcityname=this.innerText;
                   //refresh();

                });
                if(i==0)
                 { 
                   currentcityval=anchor.value;
                   currentcityname=anchor.innerText;
                 }


                var elem = document.createElement("li");
                           elem.appendChild(anchor);
                           list.appendChild(elem);

                }

}
```